# Tableau - API Call to Show Everything a User Has Access To

Tags: tableau-api

is there an API call, or a link of API calls in which I can show the following structure

```
Sites User Has Access To
 - Projects User Has Access To
 -- Workbooks User Has Access to
 --- Views User Has Access To (Including Thumbnails)
```

I'm currently using a mix of the API and directly accessing (not strictly true but that's another story) the PostgreSQL DB. It works and it s pretty neat hack, but I'd rather avoid hacks

I was using 8.3 but now on the latest v9 release

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Tableau API to do this, it seems pretty straightforward, but maybe I'm missing something.

Following API reference:
[Tableau REST API reference](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm)

1. Sign in and impersonate, use retrieved token in following API calls
2. Query sites
3. For each site query workbooks
4. For each workbook query views
5. For each view download preview image
6. Sign out

Comment: My point was the need for one single call rather than, as in your example, multiple calls

Comment: The "link of API calls" part threw me off. As for doing something like this in a the single API call - sorry I'm not aware of anything like this in Tableau.

Comment: How would I view what projects a user has access to?

Comment: Provide that user's id during sign-in (user-to-impersonate) : http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api_ref.htm#Sign_In , use returned Token to query Projects with Tableau REST API, it should do the trick.

Comment: The problem I have is that NT authentication is used on the website so can't pass username/password to authenticate, just username.

Comment: Looks like I don't fully understand what is your Tableau setup. If you use Active Directory it should be possible to set it up as a authentication method in Tableau, no impersonation should be required. If you use AD just for website, then I would need to know how are you synchronising users between Tableau and your website and what authentication method do you use to access Tableau. Maybe we could move this discussion somewhere else, comments are a bit limiting. I've updated my profile info.